# Cargar iconos Font Awesome en WordPress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Estoy intentando incorporar los iconos de Font Awesome en WordPress. Hasta el momento, he conseguido mostrarlos en una sección de las entradas donde indico el tiempo de lectura media de una entrada de la siguiente forma:

```html
<span class="readtime" title="Tiempo de lectura aproximado"><i class="far fa-clock"></i>'
```

Para cargar los iconos, tengo definidos en el `function.php` el siguiente código:

```php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_load_fa' );
function enqueue_load_fa() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'load-fa', 'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css' );
}
```

Y la clase `far fa-clock` está definida en el `CSS` así:

```css
.fa .far{
    font-family: Font Awesome\ 5 Free;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-right: 20px !important;
}
```

Ahora lo que quiero es añadir un icono a los enlaces de las entradas de la siguiente forma:

```css
.entry a::after{
    font-family: Font Awesome\ 5 Free;
    content: "\f090";
}
```

WordPress intenta cargarlo, pero me pinta en pantalla un cuadrado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna idea de lo que puede estar fallando?

Comment: Cuando pones el nombre de la fuente, escapas un espacio en blanco, pero no los demás. Las fuentes con espacios en blanco o caracteres especiales es mejor  ponerlas entrecomilladas para evitar problemas. Prueba eso a ver si funciona.

Comment: He modificado el nombre de la fuente escapando los espacios, Alvaro Montoro, pero no funciona. Aún así, no parecía ser la solución, puesto que en la clase `.fa .far` lo tengo puesto igual y el icono si que lo carga.